# Laravel-5 using fill() to update database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to use `fill()` to update a current row in the database.  However, it seems to be creating a new row instead of updating each time.

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Here's my code:

```
$reserve->where('cookie_id', 'idCode')->first();
$reserve->fill($request->all())->save();

return Redirect::to('checkout');
```

Comment: Can you post your the full function? Theres several things that could be causing this depending on how you're getting `$reverse`.

Answer (score 3):

Try something similar to this

```
$user = User::where ('cookie_id', 'idCode'); 
$new_user_data = $request->all();
$user->fill($new_user_data);
$user->save();
```

You can also try using update()

```
$affectedRows = User::where('votes', '>', 100)->update($request->all());
```

Comment: if you do $new_user_data = $request->all(); that will create an index named _token with the token value which most probably is not present in your table and hence you will get exception

Comment: true, best option is to make your own array and pass the values u r looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by your code you've misunderstood how to fetch an instance out the database. See http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Try the following

```
$reserve = Reserve::where('cookie_id', $id)->first();

$reserve->fill($request->input())->save();

return redirect()->to('checkout');
```